# If I go to Singapore, where can I get internet for my cellphone?

Tags: cellphones, singapore, internet

I want to go to Singapore for a few days. How do I access internet there? Is there a wifi? Roaming would be very expensive.

I use Indosat currently for internet.

Comment: See also: http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Singapore for mobile plans with data.

Answer (score 12):

There is a free Wifi system, which is available at many locations around Singapore called [Wireless@SG](https://www.imda.gov.sg/wireless-sg).

To connect to the network you need to be able to receive a SMS to a mobile phone (not necessarily the device you want to access Internet with). This also works with a foreign phone number. There's two networks, an open one (Wireless@SG) and a secured one (Wireless@SGx), if you want to access the second one, you need to download one of the [apps](https://www.imda.gov.sg/wireless-sg). Here's [a website of one of the operators with detailed instructions](https://www.singtel.com/personal/i/internet/broadband-on-the-go/wireless-sg).

The network is available at many public places, such as stations, hospitals, some malls and even hawker centres. However it's not always easy to find one. There is a list of [all hotspots](https://www.imda.gov.sg/-/media/imda/files/community/consumer-education/wirelless-sg/hotspot-list1.pdf?la=en), but it's really long and probably not very useful. So your best guess would be to just go somewhere and see whether it's available.

Comment: Train stations invariably have one. The app also shows the nearest hotspot to you

Comment: Relying on public wifi belongs to the previous decade. As of 2018 there's absolutely no reason not to buy a throwaway SIM card, especially in SE Asia where they're extremely cheap.

Comment: @JonathanReez agree, but if you are short on change and/or don't need/want a constant connection while on holidays, then this is a useful alternative. This is what I personally do (I live in SG) and it works quite well.

Comment: @JonathanReez One issue is that the SIN airport is milking tourists with their expensive SIM cards. https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Singapore "The lowest priced starter packs of the three providers for S$5 or S$8 are very hard to find. You won't certainly get them at the airport where only their S$30+ packages are offered, and" I could indeed only find SIM cards priced at 50 SGD or above at 1 AM at SIN. But maybe now there exists some cheap eSIM?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes, lookup eSimDB, there’s tons of options

Answer (score 5):

You can buy a prepaid SIM card (StarHub is probably the cheapest). There are wifi networks in the airport, Starbucks, etc. Completely open wifi networks are quite rare in Singapore.

Comment: I think your information might be outdated, the wireless@SG network is quite extensive.

Comment: See http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Singapore

Answer (score 3):

[This hotel](http://www.booking.com/Share-HynVco) provides a smartphone with Internet access to its guests. I've stayed there last year and used that. You can [share the connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering) with your device too.
I believe there can be more hotels providing that.